# refresh panel content when modal child is shown

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, modal-dialog

I have my main form with a panel where is drawn a 3d scene. everything is ok.

After I create a modal form that go to modify some things in the 3d scene, and I wish see the result directly without closing the modal form, but until I close the form, no changes are in the '3d' panel.

I tried to do this:

`my3dPanel.Invalidate();`

with this nothing changes;

`my3dPanel.Refresh();`

with this the panel take the 'background' init color until I close the modal form.

how can I do this?

to refresh I created a static class like this:

```
public static class EditorHelper
{
    public delegate void RefreshBridgeEventHandler();
    public static event RefreshBridgeEventHandler RefreshBridgeEvent;

    public static void NeedToNotifyParent()
    {
        if (RefreshBridgeEvent != null)
        {
            RefreshBridgeEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

and into my main window:

```
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EditorHelper.RefreshBridgeEvent += EditorHelper_RefreshBridgeEvent;
    }

    void EditorHelper_RefreshBridgeEvent()
    {
        my3dPanel.Invalidate();
        my3dPanel.Refresh();
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide simple example what your code does, when modal form is opened, where you invalidating panel and so on.

Comment: @Reniuz i've modified the message with the code

Comment: And how your 3d model is constructed/refreshed? Do you draw everything in paint event handler?

Comment: no @Reniuz , is not drawn in paint event, but i'm using Ogre3d and I use into a cli dll the method `mRoot->startRendering();`, basically is refreshed each frame using the handle of the panel

Comment: A lots of questions in my mind at the moment :) Are you sure your refresh code is accessed? How about not modal form? Do you experience same behavior? Maybe rendering is suspended when panel is not in focus?

Comment: thanks for your interest @Reniuz.. so, the code is ok, maybe vs suspend the refresh when is not focused, the modal is due that I 'm  making some custom propertygrideditor items

Comment: I understood the usage of your modal form, but you can try make non modal form and test if same problem exists. If your 3d model still not refreshing when you have non modal form try to click on panel and look how it reacts. If it renders when receives focus then we will know exact problem.

Comment: Also you can try to call my3dPanel.Update() method

Comment: the non modal form works right, with the modal form, update, refresh, invalidate, nothing happens

Comment: Maybe your rendering loop is in UI thread? When you open modal form it is paused till form is closed.